# The directory containing the assemblies for the Visual Studio Test Runner is not valid

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, continuous-integration, visual-studio-test-runner

Our CI environment setup with [TFS Server 2015 + Visual studio build tools 2017]. When I try to run C# based unit test on environment it shows this error
`TF900547: The directory containing the assemblies for the Visual Studio Test Runner is not valid ''.`

Then I tried to fix the error by fallowing ways

1. Installed VS test agent 2015 in the machine https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/lab-management/install-configure-test-agents
2. Copied `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow` from my computer to exact location to CI machine.

   3. Changed test runner from `Visual Studio Test Runner` to `MS Test Runner`

But still same error. Looks like tfs server not able to find the test agent folder. Anyone has idea how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have VS 2017 Build Tools installed only, no VS IDE on the CI environment.

> You need to install VS IDE. VS build tools doesn't contain the "*test
>   platform*". In order to run the tests, you **require to install full
>   IDE**.

Currently to run the VsTest task, the task has dependency on Visual Studio IDE.  But some changes will have in the near future.

> *We have decided to go with a '**tools installer**' which can be used to
>   get the test platform instead of needing the IDE. If you have the IDE,
>   great. If you don't, the tools installer will get the test platform on
>   the agent for you. It is already on backlog and expected to be available on VSTS in a few sprints.*

More details please take a look at the discussion in this issue: [vstest capability not detected when installed without Visual Studio](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/871)

Comment: I don't think it required to install whole Visual Studio. As this page explain in  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/lab-management/install-configure-test-agents, installing of Test Agent would be enough

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya Actually this link is talking about **test control** and **test agent**.  In tfs 2013 user need both test agents and test controls. However, with new test agent, you won't need a test controller because Agents for Microsoft Visual Studio handle orchestration by communicating with Team Services or TFS. It's explain `Will Test Agent 2015 support all the scenarios supported by Test Controller and Test Agent of Visual Studio 2013?`  And it's not mentioned VS related is not required. IDE installation is the only way to get VSTest as a working System Capability.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya This is also confirmed  from test team `nigurr` and `PBoraMSFT` " being able to run tests when Test platform is obtained through the Test Agent is on the backlog."  in this thread : https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/871